# SQLite and WHERE - T9 dictionary

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, dictionary, where-clause

I have a problem with SQLite in Android and keyword WHERE.

Currently I am writing Android App using T9 dictionary. My table looks like this:

```
        @Override
    public void onCreate( SQLiteDatabase db ){
        db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_WORDS + " (" +
                    COLUMN_ID           + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    COLUMN_CODE         + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    COLUMN_WORD         + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    COLUMN_FREQUENCY    + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    "UNIQUE( " + COLUMN_WORD + "));"
        );
    }
```

Then I load some data to it. For example for word(COLUMN_WORD) "test" my code(COLUMN_CODE) in T9 dictionary is 8378 and for word "example" my code is equal to 3926753.

Next I write new SQL query:

```
sql = "SELECT `" + COLUMN_WORD+"`,`"+ COLUMN_CODE + "` FROM `" + TABLE_WORDS + "` LIMIT 10;";
```

And next a another query:

```
code = "2";
sql = "SELECT " + COLUMN_WORD+","+ COLUMN_CODE + " FROM " + TABLE_WORDS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_CODE + "='" + code + "';";
```

And in JAVA I write: `Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery( sql, null );`

Now in the first query results are correct, but in the second I do not get expected results.

Logs are here: http://oi57.tinypic.com/f78di.jpg

**What am I doing wrong in the SQL query?** I tried using:

- WHERE `code`='2'
- WHERE `code`="2"
- WHERE `code`=2
- WHERE code='2'
- WHERE code="2"
- WHERE code=2
- WHERE `code` = '2'
- WHERE `code` = "2"
- WHERE `code` = 2
- WHERE `code` like "2"
- WHERE `code` =? and then `cursor = database.rawQuery( sql, new String[] { code } );`

All methods I have tried give me the same negative results. If you know how to solve this problem, please help me.

Best regards
Kamil4u

Full code:

```
    public List<String> getWords( String code ){
    String word;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    String sql;

    sql = "SELECT `" + COLUMN_WORD+"`,`"+ COLUMN_CODE + "` FROM `" + TABLE_WORDS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_CODE + "='" + code + "';";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery( sql, null );


    Log.i("---TEXT---",  sql );
    if( cursor != null ){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while( cursor.moveToNext() ){
            word = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( COLUMN_WORD ) );
            list.add( word );

            Log.i("---TEXT---",  "-->"+cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( COLUMN_WORD ) )+"<---->" + cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( COLUMN_CODE ) ) + "<--" );
        }
    }

    Log.i("---TEXT---",  "list( " + !list.isEmpty() + " )" + list );
    list.clear();
    sql = "SELECT `" + COLUMN_WORD+"`,`"+ COLUMN_CODE + "` FROM `" + TABLE_WORDS + "` LIMIT 10;";

    Log.i("---TEXT---",  sql );
    cursor = database.rawQuery( sql, null );
    if( cursor != null ){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while( cursor.moveToNext() ){
            word = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( COLUMN_WORD ) );
            list.add( word );

            Log.i("---TEXT---",  "-->"+cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( COLUMN_WORD ) )+"<---->" + cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( COLUMN_CODE ) ) + "<--" );
        }
    }

    Log.i("---TEXT---",  "list( " + !list.isEmpty() + " )" + list );            

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your queries with these

```
sql = "SELECT " + COLUMN_WORD + ", " + COLUMN_CODE + " FROM " + TABLE_WORDS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_CODE + "='" + code + "';";
```

and

```
sql = "SELECT " + COLUMN_WORD + ", "+ COLUMN_CODE + " FROM " + TABLE_WORDS + " LIMIT 10;";
```

***EDIT***
Your while loop is messing with it. Use it like this.

```
 while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
    word = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( COLUMN_WORD ) );
    list.add( word );

    Log.i("---TEXT---",  "-->"+cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( COLUMN_WORD ) )+"<---->" + cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( COLUMN_CODE ) ) + "<--" );
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Its clear from your log that result has changed. Now your list has values, earlier it was empty.

Comment: In my database I have record where code = 2. For example it is word "a". When I use SQL query with `where code=2` I expect any result, but my list is empty. To prove record a exist I use the second SQL query with `LIMIT 10`. You can see effects in logs.

Comment: Wow! It's working. Thanks a lot! What it's wrong in my version and why with "LIMIT 10" it was ok and with "WHERE" it was not ok?

Comment: `LIMIT 10` is also not ok. Verify it, first column value must not be there. When you use `cursor.moveToNext()` it moves to the new position. You were moving into the cursor without fetching the first position value. Change your while loop at both the places.